# Canvas resizing with JS to keep aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code to apply a pixel-effect to a video: https://jsfiddle.net/gx0wod3f/285/

```
const 
video = document.querySelector('video'),
canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w, h;

const 
paint = (width, height, scale) => {
            let 
            newWidth = width / scale,
            newHeight = height / scale;

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, width, height);
            requestAnimationFrame(paint.bind(null, w, h, scale));
},

setVariables = () => {
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
};

setVariables();

video.play();
video.addEventListener('play', paint.bind(null, w, h, 2));
```

I couldn't figure out why but the aspect ratio is always skewed, with horizontal videos the result is a squished video. I looked into methods of keeping the aspect ratio but I couldn't make it work.

Could someone give me a pointer as to what's causing the aspect ratio to change?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried calculating the difference between the 2 dimensions and resizing one accordingly when the other is resized?

for example if you want your height at 50px and your width at 100px, you want your width to be 50px if your height gets resized down to 25px. you can just calculate the aspect ratio (divide height by width) and make a simple JS script that would automatically adjust one value according to the calculated aspect ratio, if the other value was changed.